# What can I persist logs from NLog that are written to a LocalStorage in an Azure role via Azure Diagnostics?

Tags: azure, nlog, azure-diagnostics

We are using Azure SDK 2.6 and want to use NLog to write our logs in a Worker Role that we deploy to the Azure Cloud. Our plan is to save these logs to a LocalStorage that we configure for our worker role, and then have the Diagnostics extension persist these logs to a blob storage.

Setting up the LocalStorage account is straight forward enough, but when configuring Diagnostics to point at the directory we want to persist, we have to give an "Absolute path" to the directory which makes little sense in our worker role. I'm wondering how I, according to best practice, can point out my Local Storage directory for persistence with diagnostics?

(I have found a [solution](http://mode19.net/Posts/CopyLocalStorageToBlob) online that uses a batch file to create a folder on the hard drive when deploying the worker role and using this folder for storing the logs, but this does not use the LocalStorage, and does not seem to be inline with best practice of how Azure should be used.)